# Flutter: How to differentiate between app killed and app running state on a background handler

Tags: flutter

The Firebase background handler can receive data messages while the app is in background or it is in killed state also.

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onBackgroundMessage:  myBackgroundMessageHandler,
)

/// myBackgroundMessageHandler is a global function which subscribed to the onBackgroundMessage events.
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

}
```

In my use case, the app needs to handle the background messages only if the app is killed, not while it is running in the background.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: I don't think there is a way of doing this (based on some posts) but you can know when an app is in the background by implementing lifecycle methods